# SheetConverter merged and wrapped cells not being properly formatted

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the library SheetConverter to convert a range in my google spreadsheet into an html body in my email. Mostly it works perfectly! However, I have some merged cells that create some titles, and it seems the merged-ness of them gets lost using SheetConverter's method 'ConvertRange2html'. Anybody know how I could fix this? The relevant code:

```
sig= Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(!account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature;
htmlRange = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(range);
fullBody = htmlRange+"<br><br>--<br><br></p>"+sig;
GmailApp.createDraft(contacts, subject, null,{from:"test@example.com", cc: cc, htmlBody: fullBody});
```

I have attached an image of the result: I'd like the first two rows to be merged so that the paragraph is more cleanly spread out, and also so that the empty cells are not there. I have also attached an example of what we email currently by copy and pasting from the spreadsheet.

What gets generated now below:

[image]

This is the ideal one below:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report that should be filed with the author(s) of the SheetConverter library, and not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah, I do see it currently as an open bug on the library's github. However, isn't it still productive to post it here to increase the chance of it being seen by someone who has a fix?

Comment: With that logic, you should be posting your bug report on every website you can find.

Comment: Stack Overflow is the Google-endorsed help forum for GoogleAppsScript issues, so no I don't agree my logic implies I should post for help everywhere, Stack Overflow is in a class of its own and the reasonable place to post a help discussion as I have done.

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a forum. This is a website devoted to answers to programming questions. Any corporation can say "If you need support then use Stack Overflow" but that does not mean that Stack Overflow is appropriate or that their statement was reasonable. Your issue is not with Google Apps Script - your issue is with the behavior of a custom function that someone wrote and supposedly maintains. You either use their product as-is, contribute a fix to them, or write your own function to do what you want the way you want it done.

Comment: I posted the question here in the hopes of receiving an answer to the programming question of whether there is some code I can incorporate into my Apps Script that will fix this bug of the custom function. 

But sometimes there are quicker fixes than writing explicit code so I had hopes someone had seen this issue before and had found a workaround too. I think that's a reasonable use of this website.

Comment: The related [issue](https://github.com/mogsdad/SheetConverter/issues/4) was fixed