# Sending Merge Cell Format to GMAIL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I was adding a feature in our scheduling wherein I'm able to send a Sheet that copy formats but it doesn't copy the format of Merge Cells. Here's the Code Below:

Note: I add this to my library = **Mo6Ljr7ZKrMeYO9mHqOdo9oxc-w7mEonb**  [ I name this , SheetConverter ]

```js
//Sending to E-mail----------
//----------
//Convert Sheet to HTML
function convSheetAndEmail(rng, email, subj)
{
  var HTML = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng);
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subj, '', {htmlBody : HTML});
}


function SendB(){

   if (Browser.msgBox('Schedule',"Are you sure you want to send this Schedule? \\n Warning!!! this will send Immediately to the sender", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO) == "yes" ){
     
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

     var DateRS = sheet.getRange("I14");
     var EADDRS = sheet.getRange("I12");     
     var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1:F31"); // Fetching the E-mail Content to be Sent

     
     var emailAddress = EADDRS.getDisplayValue();  // Fetching the E-mail Address to be Sent
     var subject = "SCHEDULE "+ DateRS.getDisplayValue(); // Setting up the E-mail Subject to be Sent
       convSheetAndEmail(dataRange, emailAddress, subject); //Sending Line

  
   }
                   else{
                   
                        Browser.msgBox("Ops Checklist", "Send cancelled", Browser.Buttons.OK)

                   
                   }

}

//Code End here at Sending to E-mail----------
```

Sample output attached of my code:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thank you for checking my format. It's already updated. Can you help me on this matter?

Comment: Welcome. Stack Snippet snippet should be used only for *executable* HTML/CSS/JavaScript (Google Apps Script code isn't *executable*). Also question's titles should not include tags.

Comment: Regarding the question content, it's not clear what is the question. Are you the author of the library that you called "SheetConverter"?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389189/sheetconverter-merged-and-wrapped-cells-not-being-properly-formatted

Comment: @Ruben mogsdad is. https://github.com/mogsdad/SheetConverter/issues/7    I'm sure it's fixable. But no one has submitted a PR for years. Then again, avoiding merging is a basic concept in spreadsheets. Even If it is fixed,  various other problems will arise on various fronts.

Comment: Thank you for all your Feedback. I'll check on it

Comment: Do you have any suggestion Where I can find a new library for this? Since it said that the said Library that I've imported has bug on it.